# Изменение свойства контрола при открытии/закрытии сторонней программы

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка на оконной форме. По нажатию на кнопку открывается определённый текстовый файл в программе Notepad. После того, как открылся текстовый файл, кнопка на оконной форме имеет свойство `IsEnabled = false`. Закрываем программу Notepad, кнопка имеет свойство `IsEnabled = true`.

Возможно ли такую кнопку вообще сделать в WPF-приложениях? И возможно ли до запуска WPF-приложения делать проверку доступности кнопки на открытия определённого текстового файла в Notepad?

**UPDATE:**

Обновил свой пост, исходя из ответа на мой вопрос. Есть две кнопки в окне приложения: 1) Открывает нужный текстовый документ, `Visibility = Visibility.Visible` 2) Закрывает нужный текстовый документ, `Visibility = Visibility.Hidden`. На самом деле, здесь нет разницы, какое свойство задействовать у контрола, я выбрал в качестве примера свойство `Visibility`.

Открываю текстовый файл через WPF-приложение, первая кнопка пропадает, вторая появляется. Закрываю открывшийся текстовый файл через кнопку, вторая кнопка исчезает, появляется первая. Вопрос: вот теперь в этой новой ситуации возможно ли как-то отследить конкретный экземпляр открытого текстового файла в Notepad? У меня просто таких вот кнопок (или контролов, здесь нет разницы, что будет) будет несколько, к тому же, я эти кнопки (или контролы) буду программно добавлять в ListBox.

Также забыл упомянуть про ограничение открытия текстовых файлов в Notepad через WPF-приложение: я могу открыть конкретный файл не больше одного раза. Безусловно, я понимаю, что в данном открытом экземпляре программы Notepad я могу открыть другой текстовый файл, но я эту ситуацию вообще не рассматриваю, поэтому, предположим, что пользователь так делать не будет (хотя на самом деле я не знаю, как ещё эту ситуацию отслеживать программного).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы сами собираетесь открывать текстовые файлы блокнотом, то вы можете сами создать процесс блокнота и следить за процессом. Простой пример:

```
public class MyWnd : Window
{
    public MyWnd()
    {
        var btn = new Button() { Content = "Open Notepad" };
        btn.Click += (sender, args) => {
            var bt = sender as Button;
            bt.IsEnabled = false;
            var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad", @"D:\temp\test.txt");
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;                
            proc.Exited += (s, e) =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                    bt.IsEnabled = true; 
                });
            };          
            proc.Start();
        };
        this.Content = btn;
    }
}
```

[image: res]

Однако, определить, какой именно файл открыт в блокноте вы не можете. То есть если файл откроете в блокноте, но юзер потом в этом блокноте откроет другой файл - вы не узнаете об этом. Максимум, что вы можете - это пробовать следить за доступностью файла для записи, но это вам не даст гарантий, что файл закрыли в блокноте или открыли в блокноте.

**UPD**

Если за созданным процессом следить и хранить ссылку на него, то тот процесс можно вручную убить (kill) или, например, попросить блокнот закрыться (CloseMainWindow), ну или просто попробовать завершить процесс (Close).

```
public class MyWnd : Window
{
    private Process _openedFile;

    public MyWnd()
    {
        var btnOpen = new Button() { Content = "Open Notepad" };
        var btnClose = new Button() {Content = "close"};

        btnOpen.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var bt = sender as Button;
            bt.IsEnabled = false;
            var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad", @"D:\temp\test.txt");
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.Exited += (s, e) =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    bt.IsEnabled = true;
                });
            };
            _openedFile = proc;
            proc.Start();
        };

        btnClose.Click += (sender, args) => {
            if (_openedFile?.HasExited == false)
            {
                // Аккурантей выбирайте, что вам тут надо сделать
                //_openedFile.Kill();
                //_openedFile.Close();
                _openedFile.CloseMainWindow();                  
            }
        };

        var panel = new StackPanel() {Orientation = Orientation.Vertical};

        panel.Children.Add(btnOpen);
        panel.Children.Add(btnClose);

        this.Content = panel;
    }   
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть, получается, что если я добавлю вторую кнопку на WPF-приложение, которая будет закрывать текстовый файл, открытый в Notepad, не сможет конкретный экземпляр программы Notepad закрыть? Если да, то это очень плохо, поскольку по заданию мне нужно, чтобы я конкретный экземпляр программы Notepad мог закрывать. И да, я забыл написать в вопросе про ограничение: текстовый файл открывается только один раз, то есть, больше одного раза я не могу открыть текстовый файл через WPF-приложение.

Comment: Свой вопрос я дополнил выше, если вам не сложно, то можете, пожалуйста, его заново перечитать. Благодарю за ответ на мой вопрос, который вы предоставили мне выше. К сожалению, из вашего ответа я пока что не понимаю, как решить другую ситуацию, описанную в разделе UPDATE.

Comment: @Cuurjol обновил ответ